# Disable active shipping spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, spree

I am creating an e-commerce store using Rails and Spree Commerce. It took 10 minutes for me to setup everything and run. My country and state are listed in the admin configuration settings. When I'm about to check out my carts, fill in the address and hit save and continue button, I get the following error message:

> Cannot find shipping fees for selected item

In my case right now, I don't want to use active shipping gems or anything that verifies the address is available or not. I want to disable the checking function on the shipping address. I just want to let the customer fill in the shipping address only stored in the database. Tax for shipping per distance isn't necessary in my case.

Comment: Do you need to calculate shipping fees based on the customer's address? If not, just use flat rate, flat percentage, or per item shipping calculators and bypass active_shipping entirely.

Comment: Nope. I just want to bypass active shipping. Stored the shipping informations to database only.

Comment: I'm confused. "Active shipping" is not a default part of a spree install. You must choose to add the spree_active_shipping to your store. Spree can store shipping information to the database without the spree_active_shipping gem. There should be no need to bypass it. Just don't install it. https://github.com/spree-contrib/spree_active_shipping

Answer (score 3):

you can do a 3 things in this case

1. Use free shipping Promotion as @michaelmichael suggested.

Or

2. Skip the delivery step from you checkout flow. Just override the order model as follows

   ```
   Spree::Order.class_eval do
       ...
       checkout_flow do
           go_to_state :address
           # go_to_state :delivery <== remove this line
           go_to_state :payment, :if => lambda { |order| order.payment_required? }
           go_to_state :confirm, :if => lambda { |order| order.confirmation_required? }
           go_to_state :complete
           remove_transition :from => :delivery, :to => :confirm
       end
   end
   ```

   Or
3. Override this method to return true every time. (Will suggest don't use this option)

   ```
   Spree::Order.class_eval do
       ...
       def ensure_available_shipping_rates
           true
       end
   end
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Without more information I can't give a conclusive answer to your questions, but I can give some general guidelines.

I think it is very likely that you do not have zones, shipping methods, or shipping categories correctly set up.

You must have zones, shipping categories, shipping methods, and a default stock location all set up properly before shipping will work. Otherwise Spree will return the same error during checkout that you give above. Your comment that it took you 10 minutes to get the store up and running leads me to believe there's something in your setup that's missing.

Milind Phirake's answer above is good, but you should not have to override any of Spree's Order-related methods to get shipping to work. Just configure your store properly.

Refer to the [Spree user guides on shipping](https://guides.spreecommerce.com/user/shipments.html) for information on the parameters you will have to set up to get shipping to work.

Comment: The exact error message OP described correlates with the lack of a shipping method for the `zone` the `ship_address` `country` or `state` is situated in.